# combine two keys to one key in mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb

my mongodb collection like this

```
{id:jdhdhjdhdjfh，
time:2012.12.1,
longitude:121.32,
latitude:32.41}
```

how to change it like this

```
{id:jdhdhjdhdjfh，
time:2012.12.1,
GPS:[121.32,32.41]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way of doing that with a single operation. You need to iterate over all the collection documents and update each one.

It will be something like this:

```
db.collection.find().forEach(function(doc){
    db.collection.update(
        {"_id":doc._id},
        {
            "$set":{
                "GPS":[doc.longitude, doc.latitude]
            },
            "$unset" : {longitude : "", latitude : ""}
        }
    );
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way :

```
var a = db.temp.find({_id : "jdhdhjdhdjfh"}, {_id : 0, longitude : 1, latitude : 1})
var obj = {};
obj["GPS"] = [a[0].longitude, a[0].latitude]
db.temp.update( {_id : "jdhdhjdhdjfh"},
{$set : obj, $unset : {longitude : 1, latitude : 1} }
)
```

Comment: Thanks.Learn more from you.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. First, the find operation is async. Secondly, you are only updating the first document instead of all the collection.

Comment: Try it on your local! I guess, that was the requirement! Or if that wasn't then yes you can iterate over the documents.

Comment: This answer is correct.I can use this  update all documents and just change some code.